# Images taking forever to load

Tags: image, performance, load-time

I have a website www.fullyawaken.com. The pictures on it are acting very erratically. One time it loads them in 5 secs, another it takes a full 30-50 secs. I've compressed all the pictures as much as possible and they are all not more than 500 kilobytes. Anyone had this problem before? What can I do? I'm trying to do as much as possible to enable faster load time - I've enabled gzip compression optimized almost everything I can think of, but I don't know how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to start with, I tested your website with pagespeed and GTMetrix and got below results.

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.fullyawaken.com/sewTPgWd

Though you have taken care of performance to some extent, It suggests you can further optimize your website and have recommendations as well.

Most of them are like,

1. Minify javascript
2. Defer parsing
3. Optimize images (its possible to compress them more than you have)
4. serve resources from a consistent url

If you are not sure about how to do it, suggestions are also present. I would suggest do these things first and if still problem persists then you can look for design changes or dig deeper.

Let me know if you can't see those results. I have a pdf report.

Comment: Thank you Kate, I will definitely try to explore these issues further.

Comment: Welcome :) Glad I could help.